# How to check one string(including one empty space) with another string to get a Boolean output

Tags: python, string, boolean

How to check one string(including one empty space)  with another string to get a Boolean output

```
def check_win(puzzle: str, solution: str) -> bool:

    """
    Returns True if the game is won, given the puzzle and the solution, and
    False otherwise. Example of calling check_win:
        >>> check_win("abcdefgh ", "abcdefghi")
        True
        >>> check_win("dabecghf ", "abcdefghi")
        False

    Parameters:
        puzzle (str): a given string which needed to be matched with solution.
        solution (str): a solution string against the given puzzle

    Returns:
        (bool): returns true if two string matched, false otherwise. 
    """
    return puzzle == solution
```

For the first example it should be TRUE, but with the code I am getting False,as it is not counting the space as a exception.

How can I get the first example as TRUE, that means ("abcdefgh ", "abcdefghi") consider same with a space as exception in first string?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve your problem?

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more what exactly should happen? Is the space only an exception at the end, or anywhere in the string? Are both `puzzle` and `solution` always the same length? Once you clarify, it'll be easier for others to help. You may even find that you can then solve it yourself!

Comment: @sabik The space is an exception anywhere in the string.

Comment: @AllanWind, I have done  ````return (puzzle+" ") == solution

Comment: Does space means any character can take its place? Like ' '=='i' in first case?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is what you need to do:

```
return solution in puzzle
```

This is not "string match" though.

Answer (score 0):

I sorted it out. I had to opt out last index for both of the puzzle and solution ,then i ran the check code.

Thanks guys

Comment: It may pass your test but I doubt that is correct.